# Issue on #2 of App Customization Specialist

Tags: trailhead, superbadges

*Challenge Not yet complete... here's what's wrong:
The 'Volunteer Organization' field's filter is not configured correctly.*

I have created the Volunteer Organization Status field on the Account object, have set up the Volunteer Organization MD from Volunteer Activity to Account with the following Filter lookup criteria

*Volunteer Organization connects Volunteer Activity to Account with the option of roll-up summary fields. Only accounts with the record type we created of status Accepting Activities should be eligible to select*.

```
    (Volunteer Organization: Account Record Type equals Volunteer Organization Account) 
and (Volunteer Organization: Volunteer Organization Status equals Accepting Activities)
```

I have also setup a permission set to open edit access to Organization Status field, as asked.

Comment: Guys this issue is [already on meta](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1925/2995). Posts which contain or solicit wholesale solutions to a challenge will be removed, but this post appears to do neither. It doesn't really ask anything and could certainly be improved. But it does not seem to violate our consensus about Trailhead questions. Flags declined.

Comment: I'm having the same issue with the same configuration. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

This Lookup filter settings should work without any issues! I have completed the step without any issues.

See Pic: [image: Lookup Filter]

Regards,

Adithya

Comment: Thank you. That's what I did. I will start from scratch in a new Playground.